# Jquery Slider With Fading

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am thinking about using the easySlider plug-in to create a banner slider on my page but I want to get the effect of the banner images to fade in instead of sliding from right to left. Does anyone know of a good plug-in that will allow this or if easySlider allows this? I read the documentation and it didn't look like it had this option.

Answer (score 0):

i think this plugin useful for u

http://smoothgallery.jondesign.net

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [link](http://www.serie3.info/s3slider/) to a plugin that does fading.  The examples show captions being used as well, but that should be easy to strip out if desired.